# Do you know of any public circular/angular dataset?

Tags: dataset, circular-statistics

I've been trying to locate and access circular/angular datasets for my research.

I'm particularly interested in datasets that distribute according to a mean centered circular distribution with proper references for citation. Also, some insights in finding this type of data for the future will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R package [`circular`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circular/index.html) contains a number of data-sets with circular variables, properly referenced.